# Render instagram blockquote

Tags: html, json, reactjs, instagram

In instagram there is a share button
[image]

Where u can get a html like:

```html
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div><p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BGUPwmztyzw/" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Фото опубликовано Luna Bear  (@luna_newfie)</a> <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2016-06-06T14:27:08+00:00">Июн 6 2016 в 7:27 PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

It works when to render it as html, so it replaces it with iframe, but when to use in react it does not render and shows emty

```js
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: content} } />
```

[image]

Comment: I think you don't need render <script> inside react component you can include Instagram library as usual script tag on page in header (because script marked as asynchronous) - http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44682/

Comment: @Alexander i guess it's not it, i added a setTimeout to ur code and now it does not work, and i've tried to add script to header

Comment: please show me your example.

Comment: @Alexander sorry there is an example https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44687/

Comment: @Alexander run `start` and it works, setTimeout for start and it does not

Comment: version for `setTimeout` - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44689/

Comment: Why it's not working anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You are violating CORS, take a look at your console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.instagram.com/ajax/bz. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Instead of using raw parsing take a look at [Instagram's API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

PS `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should be used with caution. Quoting React's official documentation:

> Improper use of the innerHTML can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. Sanitizing user input for display is notoriously error-prone, and failure to properly sanitize is one of the leading causes of web vulnerabilities on the internet.